# Create records with flow on update via API

Tags: flow

I have a flow that creates record and this flow is invoked by a process, it works fine when I update and meet the criteria for process to run, on salesforce but when I update to meet the criteria for the same process, the record is not created with the flow. What could be the problem here ?

Comment: you might want to elaborate here -- the question as it stands is ambiguous

Comment: Yes, please give us more details.  Can you please give us the criteria your Process Builder is using to invoke the Flow?  Also, what is the difference between YOU and the API?  Are there different Profiles or Roles associated (going back to the criteria in the Process Builder, trying to find a delta).

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clearer. The criteria is simple when opportunity is closed when then it should generate an order record . But when the opportunity stage is changed via API, the order is not created. The profiles  for both of the normal and API users are same. 

I was wondering if this is some kind of limitation with flow ?